# Repeatedly adding/removing class will slow things down?

Tags: jquery, performance, scroll

So I want to do a couple of things on scroll with jQuery...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  //so it's not overly aggressive calling the funciton
  setTimeout(function(){check_scroll()}, 50);
});
```

And then...

```
function check_scroll(){
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop()
  if(scroll > 100) {
    $("#fixed").addClass("fixed");
  }
  else
    $("#fixed").removeClass("fixed");  
};
```

So, my question is, #fixed will have the class ".fixed" most of the time, so if I repeatedly ask jQuery to add it, will it be non-performant? Should I first check if it has the class and then try to add it?

It seems fine as it is now, but my app will grow and there will be a lot of js going on, so I want to milk every bit of performance possible.

Comment: If you are worried about performance because you are calling this often, you should cache `$("#fixed")` and `$(window)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are really worried about performance, the $('#fixed') is going to be of greater concern. You should stick the result of that in a variable unless #fixed is going to be something different every-time you query for it.

The question of adding and removing a class is mostly, "it depends". What does adding and removing the class actually do? Does it change the layout of the page or are you using it as a flag for something else? If it changes the layout of the page and then you have no choice. If it doesn't, then you could use the [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data) method instead to store state which will avoid [reflow](http://code.google.com/speed/articles/reflow.html) (the major performance issue with adding/removing classes).

I am also concerned about how many times your check_scroll function is going to be called in practice. You are not cancelling previous setTimout events and so, you will end up with a bunch of setTimeout calls. Probably you want something more like:

```
(function() {
  var timeout = null, fixed = $('#fixed'), win=$(window),
   check_scroll = function() {
      var scroll = win.scrollTop();
      fixed.toggleClass("fixed", scroll > 100);
      timeout=null;
   }
   win.scroll(function() {
      if (timeout) {
         // only do once every 50ms
         return;
      }
      timeout = setTimeout(check_scroll, 50);
   });
```

Comment: I agree with caching the result of $("#fixed").  It doesn't matter if the content changes, all he is doing is toggling a class. I'm guessing he is adding the class to something he wants to stay stuck at the top of the page.

Comment: I agree that he wants it to stay stuck. But there is more involved in the decision about if the class toggling matters because people use class to store non-visual state and that is better handled with .data(). Writing to className will trigger a reflow, reading normally won't and since jQuery checks, it probably doesn't matter other than the overhead to parse the className and check.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you will take a performance hit for calling addClass with a class that already exists on the element.

You could use this block of code and it should perform well since toggleClass first uses hasClass before calling addClass or removeClass:

```
$("#fixed").toggleClass("fixed", scroll > 100);
```

Comment: prefer toggle over hasClass, addClass because jquery takes care of the current state

Comment: Thanks T B that snippet is golden!

Answer (score 0):

This code should be fine,

The jquery file is only loaded once in a browser and once it is loaded it is fully operational. The browser doesn't need to reload it everytime it calls to the file to execute a command.

Your code should be fine, in my opinion.